# Relative clause - situational instances

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, indefinite-pronouns

I was taught “which” can be used to refer to a situation or event in the preceding clause, as well as referring directly to the person or thing immediately in front of “which”. But how do you tell the difference?

1. He bought some flowers, which were her favourites.
   -> Simple enough, here “ which” refers to the flowers.

*However in the example below,*

2. Many parents had to homeschool their children during the pandemic, which was difficult.
   -> here the “which” is supposed to be substituting the event of homeschooling, but how can you justify that it won’t be confused with “parents” or “pandemic”, since pandemic is immediately preceding “which”, and parents are the subject of the clause?

Many thanks to the lovelies.

Comment: I don’t think the link refers to the issue posed in the question. The referent for *which* can be an entire sentence. It is the writer’s task to figure out what’s confusing or misleading and fix it.

Comment: The answer is that you can't always tell in some sentences. If a writer wants to be clear (they might want to be ambiguous, after all - they're creating effects), they can phrase a sentence in a context so it isn't ambiguous, but that's hard, because written English sentences don't include intonation and other non-lexical features that distinguish conversation and disambiguate sentences. Written English is like smoke signals. (Though _which_ can't refer to a person; you hafta use _who_ instead)

Comment: From an editing perspective, the way to escape such ambiguity is by providing greater clarity to the construction. You can accomplish this by positioning the "which" immediately after the intended referent (e.g., by rephrasing the sentence as "During the pandemic, many parents had to homeschool their children, which was difficult.")  or by adding further wording (e.g., "Many parents had to homeschool their children during the pandemic, which was a difficult task."). In the reordering approach, "which was" follows "to homeschool their children" and logically attaches to the whole phrase ...

Comment: ... as the nearest possible referent, since subject/verb disagreement between "children" and "was" disqualifies "children" as the possible intended referent. In the additional clarification approach, "a difficult task" disqualifies "pandemic" as a possible referent, since a pandemic isn't a task; this leaves the whole phrase "to homeschool their children during the pandemic" as the nearest logical referent.